# what is my HAProxy version?

Tags: version, haproxy

I installed HAProxy for load ballancing before. How can I check what is my haproxy version which installed before in mu ubuntu?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

haproxy --version

If you want to see the package info on Ubuntu,  you can use 'aptitude show haproxy'  to get version and other details about what's installed.

Comment: `haproxy -vv` will give you more details of how it was built, which should include the all important OpenSSL version.

Answer (score 19):

i used the command on CentOS 5

```
/usr/sbin/haproxy -v
```

Answer (score 1):

On **Red Hat Enterprise Linux** is:

`haproxy -v`

Answer (score 1):

`haproxy -vv`

Will give the below details

1. Version
2. Build Options
3. Default settings like `maxconn, bufsize, maxrewrite, maxpollevents`
4. Built with which `OpenSSL` version
5. Running on which `OpenSSL` version
6. Available polling systems
7. Libraries version
8. Which compression algorithms supported

Answer (score -1):

Suppose if you run haproxy using docker

```
docker exec -it <container_name> haproxy --version
```

for e.g

```
docker exec -it haproxy haproxy --version
```